# Encode JSON data from PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I'm sending an `NSString` containing `JSONData` from my iOS device/simulator to my server via `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest`.

My JSON string in app is:

```
jsonString---->{
  "ACTION" : "MyActn",
  "PARAM_1" : "myParm1"
  "PARAM_2" : "myParm2",
}
```

The `NSData` I am sending is of the form(not understandable, which I think is **secure** :D ):

```
7b225041 52414d5f 32223a22 6d795061 726d3222 2c224143 54494f4e 223a224d 79416374 6e222c22 50415241 4d5f3122 3a226d79 5061726d 31227d
```

and in server side, I have the following code:

```
// The code is just for studying JSON parsing and data communication in iOS and PHP
<?php
  data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The page echos the actual JOSN data array, and I am sending the data and fetching this result via my Objective C code:

```
 NSData *sendData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                          returningResponse:nil 
                                                      error:nil];
 NSString *returningString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:sendData 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

when I NSLog the 'returningString', it prints the JSON directly like (readable, I think it is **unsecure** also :D):

```
{"PARAM_2":"myParm2","ACTION":"MyActn","PARAM_1":"myParm1"}
```

**So, My Question is**:

- Is the method I am following is correct?
- And how can I convert the encoded JSON data string to unreadable format
  in PHP code?
- And If I do so, will that encoded string can be decoded via `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithDat`.

Note: Please don't mention any external libraries, as I would like to use `NSJSONSerialization`. :)

Please forgive me if I am wrong in somewhere. I am just a person trying to learn JSON parsing in iOS

Comment: The code you "think is secure" is just a hexadecimal representation of the  JSON string: "{"PARAM_2":"myParm2","ACTION":"MyActn","PARAM_1":"myParm1"}" and there is nothing secure about it. You really need to learn about different data representations such as hexadecimal. And that the same data (bytes) can be repsented different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So what is the basic way to protect my JSON String while I'm echoing it to my iOS device (while using NSURLConnection)?

Comment: The simpliest is to use SSL (https), the data will be encrypted by the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the method I am following is correct?

Depends on how you define correct. It should be working. But if you have no good reason to make an synchronous request you should really make an asynchronous request to stop blocking the user interface etc.

> And how can I convert the encoded JSON data string to unreadable format in PHP code?

It may be hard to read, but it certainly isn't unreadable. It's just a byte representation of your JSON data which could easily be "reverse engineered" (can't even call that reverse engineering). That is in **no** way "secure". If you really want secure data this way you have to use a real encryption.

> And If I do so, will that encoded string can be decoded via NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithDat

If you convert your JSON to bytes in PHP (can't tell you how that's done) you should be able to decode that to JSON with the NSData initializer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So how do I convert my JSON in PHP to byte representation?

Comment: I don't know. But your server responding in plain JSON text is fine. You should secure your communication otherwise, e.g. some form of authentication etc. Why would you want your server responding in "NSData" anyway?